# "Any" - verb/subject agreement

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which is correct: "we agree to notify you if any of our intentions **has** changed" or "we agree to notify you if any of our intentions **have** changed"?

Answer (score 0):

> we agree to notify you if any of our intentions have changed

Intentions refer to the plural form of the verb 'intention' and hence, 'have' is the correct form of verb to be used.